# List items from another list that have a value against them

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 columns, the first column has data in it, against which the second one has some data.

Now I need to get a list of all the items in the first column in the third column.

The sheet as as below

```
Name    | QTY | ACTIVE
----------------------
Apple   |     |
----------------------
Oranges | 10  |
----------------------
Pears   | 5   |
----------------------
Plums   |     |
```

It needs to look like this

```
Name    | QTY | ACTIVE
----------------------
Apple   |     | Oranges
----------------------
Oranges | 10  | Pears
----------------------
Pears   | 5   |
----------------------
Plums   |     |
```

How can I do this either using a formula or a script.

What i've put above is just an example, its actually a long list of items against which there may or may not be quantities, therefore I only need a list of the items with quantities against them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using google sheets then you can use a filter function.  Enter the formula and all the results will be listed in the cells below.  Only items from column A that have data in Column B will be displayed.

```
=filter(A2:A,NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
```

How it works

```
=filter(range,criteria)
```

You can also pull both the Name and Quantity by widening your range to include column B

```
=filter(A2:B,NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
```

**Note:** If you get a **#REF!** error then you may not have left enough blank cells below your filter cell for the results to be displayed.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en

Comment: Thanks a ton, that was the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: not a problem.  you can mark it as the accepted answer if it's what you were looking for.  Don't try and use filter() in Excel as it's only a Sheets thing.  It is possible in Excel but a lot more complicated.